# Flex property not working in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, flexbox

```
 .rq-search-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border-radius: 2px;
    z-index: 30;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 15em;
  }
```

It's perfectly working with chrome, Mozilla browsers but not working in Safari browser.

I was already tried many ways like -web-kit-flex, etc. but not working.
please suggest me!

Comment: Try add `display:-webkit-flex `

Comment: vendor prefixes css properties should be written above the standard css properties.

Comment: If you're writing CSS in a daily basis, [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) is a must-have (with a Browserslist configuration). You won't have to care about those prefixes and won't be _able_ to forget one (or add one not neceessary or that has never existed), write in a non-functional order, have to remove manually when you don't support some (now) old browser, etc Needs some tooling but there's a reason why it's used by so many devs ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this style `display:-webkit-flex`

similarly for all the browser use below css

```
display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
```

Your code

```
.rq-search-container {

 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff; 
 display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
 display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
 display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
 display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
 flex-direction: row; 
 align-items: flex-start;
 border-radius: 2px; 
 /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); margin-top: 45px;*/ 
 z-index: 30;

}
```

Comment: hi  Dinesh, i was tried this code but not get it to reflect!

Comment: can you please post updated styles? @PrasannaRaja

Comment: position: relative;

  width: 100%;

  background: #fff;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border-radius: 2px;

  z-index: 30;

  -webkit-display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;

Comment: superb!, its working! thanks bro!....

Comment: @PrasannaRaja Glad to help